# Dual varieties and nodal sections

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, duality

Let $X$ be a(n even dimensional) smooth complex projective variety in $\mathbb{P}^N$, and let $X^{\vee}$ be its dual variety; up to an higher degree Veronese embedding of $X$, I assume that $X^{\vee}$ is a hypersurface (that is, $X$ has no *defect*).

By construction, for any $H\in X^{\vee}$, the corresponding hyperplane cuts $X$ in a singular section $X_H=X\cap H$.

By Theorem of Reflexivity, for any $(P,H)\in X\times X^{\vee}_{sm}$ such that $H$ is tangent to $X$ at $P$ is equivalent to say the hyperplane corresponding to $P$ in $\overset{\vee}{\mathbb{P}^N}$ is tangent to $X^{\vee}$ at $H$.

**Question**: assuming that the singular points of $X_H$ are only double ordinary (for simplicity, all singularities are *nodes*, so $X_H$ is a *nodal section*), what can I say about $H\in X^{\vee}$?

Comment: What kind of property are you asking for? $H$ is a smooth point if and only if $X_H$ has exactly one ordinary double point. What else?

Comment: 1) I am not assuming that $X_H$ has exactly only one node. 2) How can I see the equivalence between the smoothness of $H$ and the "nodality" of $X_H$?

Comment: One reference is SGA 7, Exp. XVII, Proposition 3.5. If you have $n$ nodes, $X^{\vee}$ has $n$ branches locally around $H$, each branch being smooth.

Comment: Perfect! This is very enlightening.

Comment: Also see Tevelev's [Projectively Dual Varieties](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0112028).

Comment: Tevelev, in that paper\book, remarks principally the case of dual plane curves. Thank you the same.